# Why does a lock_guard on a mutex reference produce C26110

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17, std

The following code in a Visual Studio Professional 2019 project (version 16.3.6) produces a warning:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>

class Foo {
public:
    mutable std::recursive_mutex _writingMutex;
    std::recursive_mutex& writingMutex() const { return _writingMutex; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo a;
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(a.writingMutex()); // produces C26110
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock2(a._writingMutex); // no warning
}
```

The first lock produces the warning [C26110](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c26110?view=vs-2019):

> Warning   C26110  Caller failing to hold lock 'lock' before calling function 'std::lock_guard::~lock_guard'

Why is this so? Does passing the mutex as reference not work?

Comment: can't reproduce with recent visual studio; https://godbolt.org/z/LEp57M. please provide a [mre] with visual studio version

Comment: @AlanBirtles added the version (Visual Studio Professional, 16.3.6) and the missing includes to the question. The project is without pre-compiled headers, freshly created via File->New -> Project . Does this fulfill the requirements for a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Could it be that it is an IntelliJ issue? When I activate `/WX` (treat warnings as errors), the solution still compiles, yet the "Error list" window shows the warning and the code line has a green underline

Comment: Error codes >10000 are code analysis errors, not compilation errors. Apparently in this particular case nested locking triggers a false positive. Report it to Microsoft (Help-> Report issue...)

Comment: @rustyx and AlanBirtles: Thanks for taking a look. I answered my own question based on your comments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the compilation result of Alan and the comment of rustyx, I will answer my own question:

This is likely to be a code analysis bug in Visual Studio. Looks like C26110 can't recognize a mutex via a reference. The issue was reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/670717/incorrect-lock-warnings-by-analyzer-c26110.html) and I added my minimal example as comment there. The issue persists in the most recent version 16.3.7 as well